# Shell Scripting: Reading in undisclosed amount of files & invoking a sh file

Tags: file, unix, io, sh, tar

I am writing a shell script that will create a self extracting tar file. My issue is the specifications for "prompting" the user, i.e. there is no prompt. The user may enter any amount of files they choose(may it be 1 file, 3 files, whatever). The script needs to run directly from the shell by typing:

```
mk tarName f1 f2 f3
```

The only way I have known to run files in the past is to type:

```
./myFile.sh
```

So:
1. How do I invoke a file from just a word (i.e. "mk") 2. How do I allow the user to type in any number of files without specifying in my code how many the read call should be expecting

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose one of:

   - place the `mk` program in a directory that is in your $PATH.
   - create an alias: `alias mk=/full/path/to/mk`
   - create a shell function `mk() { /full/path/to/mk "$@"; }`
2. In a shell script, the array-like `"$@"` (with the quotes) construct contains your command line arguments. You can iterate over the args with

   ```
   for arg in "$@"; do ...; done
   # or, a shorthand for the above
   for arg do ...; done
   ```

Comment: Okay 1. worked thank you! I am just wondering for 2., the first thing after mk is the name of the tar file and everything that follows will be the files I'm including, is there a way to skip tarName, or read it in separately from the file names that follow

Comment: Yes, you would just shift the tarname off the args: `tarName=$1; shift; for file do ...; done`